# storing different java types in the same list of lists?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

If i have a dog, cat and mouse class, - create a few objects of each animal and add them to each indivual dog, cat and mouse type specific list.

Can i then store them in the same list of lists as objects ?

i have tried with:

```
 List<Object> animalData = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then tried adding the ex: mouse array to the animal array without succes.

what i want:

```
list animals<<dogs>,<cats>,<mouses>>
```

Comment: if Dog,Cat and Mouse extend Animal, then you can add them to List<Animal>

Comment: Generic lists are homogeneous - they contain a bunch of things all of the same type. If your list contains three different things, it's not a list. It's an object with three fields. You could write an `AnimalData` class, and give it fields like `List<Dog> dogList`, `List<Cat> catList` and `List<Mouse> mouseList`.

Comment: Read up on polymorphism to get a hint at how to solve this problem. 
You can Always start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make them all extend a single class then yes you can.

```
class Animal {

}
class Cat extends Animal {

}
class Dog extends Animal {

}
class Mouse extends Animal {

}
List<Animal> animals = Arrays.asList(new Cat(), new Dog(), new Mouse());
```